# Applications to replace iTunes for iPod synchronization?

Tags: video, sound, software-recommendation, podcast

I need to synchronise my iPod Nano (5th generation) with music and podcasts (video and audio).
I can use Rhythmbox for music, but does not seem to work with Podcast.

So, what application can I use to synchronize my podcats ?

Edit : 
After a week of fight with my iPod Nano, i've definitively uninstalled Banshee and i finally use Rhythmbox. 
Why ? because several times my music and podcast list in my iPod have been corrupted (3 times the same podcast, podcast in music and music in podcast, wrong covers ...)

I start this new week testing RhythmBox....

Edit 2 : finally found a solution with gPodder, read my answer for details

Comment: After a week of fight with my iPod Nano, i've definitively uninstalled Banshee and i finally use Rhythmbox. Why ? because several times my music and podcast list in my iPod have been corrupted (3 times the same podcast, podcast in music and music in podcast, wrong covers ...)

Comment: My new test with RhythmBox begun yesterday : - iPod Nano reset with  iTunes on a Windows XP station - RhythmBox loaded with music and podcasts - iPod Synchronization => OK everything is well defined in the iPod, i see music in the music library and podcasts in the podcast library, good covers ... but ... but no sound at all when i start playing music or podcast on the iPod ... grrrrr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many tests, i found a solution to my problem  :

- Rhythmbox **or** Banshee for music
- **gPodder** for podcasts

This configuration works fine with iPod Nano 5th generation

---

Details  :

- Banshee corrupts iPod library if you synchronize podcasts (3 times the same podcast, podcast in music and music in podcast, wrong covers ...)
- Rhythmbox synchronize every podcasts but convert video podcasts into audio podcasts (very long synchronization process with high CPU usage)
- [gPodder](http://gpodder.org/) version 2.9 works fine with audio and video podcasts (add gPodder ppa for the 2.9 version : deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thp/gpodder/ubuntu maverick main )

Answer (score 13):

[Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) is the best I know.

Comment: I confirm that synchronization works fine and Banshee really looks like better than Rhythmbox. Merci Julien !

Comment: You're welcome ;) You should take a look at Daniel Rodrigues's answer too and use banshee-team PPA to get the most up-to-date version.

Comment: I edited the subjet, finally Banshee is not working correctly in my configuration :( I test RhythmBox but meet problems too.

Answer (score 10):

Banshee 1.8 is undoubtedly the best one. You can simply install Banshee from Software-Center, then add the Banshee-Team repository (trough **Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software > Add**, and then fill in with `ppa:banshee-team/ppa`), and update your system trough the Update Manager.

Banshee will be in Applications > Sound and Video > Banshee Media Player. You can now plug-in your iPod, activate Banshee Podcast Plugin trough **Edit > Preferences > Extensions**, add your podcast and configure syncing in the iPhone's pane in Banshee.

Comment: Thx for your answer Daniel, i did not flag it as the best answer because Julien answered first but your answer is more complete.

Comment: No prob, I'm glad to help :)

Comment: I like how you can get Banshee for ever OS known to mankind but Windows... I lol'd at that...

Answer (score 3):

I would give *[Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/en/screenshots)* a look, I have used it in the past good support as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use Banshee or Rythmbox is indiferent, the two have a good integration with iPod.

Answer (score 3):

Rhythmbox supports podcasts and doesn't require additional plugins to do so. I use it myself and can confirm that it works.

Go to "Edit > Preferences > Podcasts" to set up the folder where your podcasts will be downloaded and how often to check for new episodes.

What version of Rhythmbox do you have and which version of Ubuntu? I run Lucid with rhythmbox 0.13.1

Comment: You're right, RhythmBox works fine finally (wrong plugin enabled). But seems like after few hours of test, Banshee became my fav audio app. Thx for your answer

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Floola I use if for my ipod video classic it downloads podcasts and I can add music/audiobooks in mp3 format or apples formats. It also support album art.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home) for this.

> gtkpod is a graphical user interface for the Apple iPod for Unix-like systems, written using the GTK+ toolkit.
>
> gtkpod allows you to:
>   * Read your existing iTunesDB (i.e. import the existing contents of your iPod including playcounts, ratings and on-the-go playlists).
>   * Add MP3, WAV, M4A (non-protected AAC), M4B (audio book), podcasts, and various video files (single files, directories or existing playlists) to the iPod.
>   * [..]

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is [Exaile](http://www.exaile.org/) It's goal is to be like Amarok, built for GTK.

Comment: I tried Exaile but did not find a way to synchronize podcasts