# Can Ghost Tunes be a replacement for Ubuntu One?

Tags: music, itunes

I have used a lot of Windows and Apple programs in the past, and now I want to switch to Ubuntu. Problem is I love music and my iTunes library...

So I want to know how to get all my music and put it into an Ubuntu music player. And I also want to know how to get music without the iTunes store. I like Ghost Tunes but I don't know if it works with Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applications to replace iTunes for iPod synchronization?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5537/applications-to-replace-itunes-for-ipod-synchronization)

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5537/applications-to-replace-itunes-for-ipod-synchronization If this is not what you're looking for, leave a comment.

Comment: No im asking about ghost tunes. That link doesn't mention that at all.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the help department at Ghost Tunes and they said it does work on Linux. It is recommended that you use Chrome browser for it to work well.